# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 255

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox, pytest

I am trying to run a selenium test but getting the above error. My geckodriver version is 0.31.0 and firefox browser version is 100 and selenium version is selenium == 4.1.0. Any idea how I can fix this?

below is my conftest.py

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as ff_service

    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    driver_path = ff_service(r"/usr/bin/geckodriver")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=driver_path,options = options)  #getting error at this line
    driver.maximize_window()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met this error as you!
I checked my geckdriver.log(in the dir you python you xxx.py)
and found the true reason is

> XPCOMGlueLoad error for file
> libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> Couldn't load XPCOM.

so you  could solve this error through installing libgtk-3